Using specific Google font globally for Next.js project working only for default / route
I want to make 'Roboto' global font for my Next.js project. Here is my main layout file where I was trying to make it accoding to documentation.
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Roboto } from "next/font/google";

import "./globals.scss";

const roboto = Roboto({
  weight: "400",
  subsets: ["latin"],
  variable: "--font-roboto",
  display: "swap",
});

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={roboto.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}


Here is my global.scss file
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: var(--font-roboto);
}

I also have this component for login route (src/pages/login/index.tsx)
const Login = () => {
    return <button>Random button</button>
};

export default Login;

and when I'm adding this line:
import '../../app/globals.css';

all is working. But I don't want to import global.css file in every file. I want import in just once in main leyout file and thats all.

I tried the same thing and it works for me. I only import globals.scss at layout, and every change I made in const Roboto changed all other components. My code:
//layout.tsx
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Roboto } from "next/font/google";

import "./globals.scss";

const roboto = Roboto({
  weight: "700",
  style: "italic",
  subsets: ["latin"],
  variable: "--font-roboto",
  display: "swap",
});

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={roboto.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}

//page.tsx
import Login from "./_components/login";
import Test from "./_components/test";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Test />
      <Login />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;

//test.tsx
const Test = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>hello</div>
      <div>world</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Test;

//login.tsx
const Login = () => {
  return <button>Random button</button>;
};

export default Login;

//globals.scss
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: var(--font-roboto);
}


//globals.scss after changing margin

* {
  margin: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: var(--font-roboto);
}


